# Instance does not have a volume attached at root

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, root, amazon-ami

I recently started trying out EC2 servers and came across an issue when trying to get an instance back up from a snapshot (which is another odd issue I had, because you can't change root snapshots in the launch setup) I tried quite a few of the answers on here and still nowhere...

AWS shows that it is attached and assigned as xvda but that's not root I guess?

[image: AWS shows that it is attached and assigned as xvda but that's not root i guess?]

Comment: This question belongs on another Stack site .. Like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: So, are you saying that the instance won't boot? Did you erase the "Volume ID" column in your screenshot? It would normally show a value there. What is the status of the instance after starting it?

Comment: It will not boot. I get

Failed to start the instance i-*omitted* 
Invalid value 'i-*omitted*' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/xvda)